# Javascript website security - global variables

Tags: javascript, html, security, web

Total newbie here. I'm working on a website which takes some user inputs, takes the inputs and pass it on to the next page, this process goes on for about 5 pages.

My question is, since I'm passing variables, I've declared a global variable but it's directly accessible in the console under inspect elopements. (For example, I have a variable named "activities", I realized I can just type "activities" in the console on the browser's inspect element and the content will show up, I can edit it to however I want too).

This is obviously super not secure, just wondering what's a better approach to handle these. And also, any other general security tips would be great. I will eventually pass the data into a database.

Below is my code in helper.js:

```
var activities = []

function removeA(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

function select_activities(b){
  if (b.classList.contains('active')) {
    $(b).removeClass('active');
    removeA(activities, b.innerHTML);
  }
  else {
    $(b).addClass('active');
    activities.push(b.innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Here's my html:

```
<script src="scripts/helpers.js"></script>

  <div class="form-group">
    <p>What are the activities you're looking for:</p>

    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="select_activities(this)">Sports</button>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="select_activities(this)">Music</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not think there is a way to "protect" JavaScript variables. JavaScript is controlled *by the client* and there is nothing to stop the JavaScript interpreter from accessing the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untrusted clients are just that - untrusted. They should be used for input and display only. Anything you don’t want them to change directly should be done on the server or at least revalidated on the server prior to storage/processing.

So in your case, I wouldn’t worry about the insecurity of the global variables, but I WOULD validate it against the business rules on the server once it’s submitted.